# SQL Server : group by calculated column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with columns like this:

[image]

I want to know the average compliance rate for every question for that period. 
I am passing start dates and end dates as parameters to query.

So if I want for two periods I am passing `@StartDate` (e.g. 1/6/17) and `@EndDate` (e.g. 30/6/17) for first period and `@StartDate2` (1/10/17) and `@EndDate2` (31/10/17) for second period.

My SQL query is:

```
;WITH tmpTab AS
(
    SELECT
        question, 
        SUM((CASE WHEN AnswerValue = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) Met,
        SUM((CASE WHEN AnswerValue = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) NA,
        SUM((CASE WHEN (ISNULL(AnswerValue,3) <> 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) MetNotMet,
        DATENAME(DAY, @StartDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) + ' ' + 
            DATENAME(YEAR, @StartDate) + ' To ' + DATENAME(DAY,@EndDate) + ' ' +
            DATENAME(MONTH, @EndDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, @EndDate) AS RepMonthAndYear
    FROM
        tableA 
    WHERE
        startdate >= @StartDate AND endate <= @EndDate
    GROUP BY
        Question

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        question, 
        SUM((CASE WHEN AnswerValue = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) Met,
        SUM((CASE WHEN AnswerValue = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) NA,
        SUM((CASE WHEN (ISNULL(AnswerValue,3) <> 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) MetNotMet,
        DATENAME(DAY,@StartDate2)+' '+DATENAME(MONTH,@StartDate2)+' '+DATENAME(YEAR,@StartDate2)+ ' To ' + DATENAME(DAY,@EndDate2)+' '+DATENAME(MONTH,@EndDate2)+' '+DATENAME(YEAR,@EndDate2) AS RepMonthAndYear
    FROM
        tableA  
    WHERE
        startdate >= @StartDate2 AND endate <= @EndDate2
    GROUP BY 
        Question
)
SELECT 
    Question, Met, NA, MetNotMet,
    CASE WHEN (Met) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ROUND(((CONVERT(FLOAT,(Met))/(MetNotMet))* 100),4) END as CompRate
FROM
    tmpTab
```

In this SQL query, I need to group by `RepMonthAndYear` column also which I can not do as it is a calculated column. I get an error "invalid column".

And if I use this `GROUP BY` clause:

```
(DATENAME(DAY,@StartDate2)+' '+DATENAME(MONTH,@StartDate2)+' '+DATENAME(YEAR,@StartDate2)+ ' To ' + DATENAME(DAY,@EndDate2)+' '+DATENAME(MONTH,@EndDate2)+' '+DATENAME(YEAR,@EndDate2) )
```

I get this error:

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

How can I solve this problem?

Is there any other way to know average rate group by particular periods?

Comment: Can you provide expected result for your input?

Comment: You try to group only by variables, it will not do anything

Comment: Your calculated column `RepMonthAndYear` is **const**, so you do not need to group by it. Just use `GROUP BY question` only.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following Test Data and your SQL I get what you discibe.

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
   question     VARCHAR(50),
   AnswerValue  INT,
   startdate    DATE,
   endate       DATE
);

INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question A', 1, '2017-06-25', '2017-06-26');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question A', 1, '2017-06-27', '2017-06-27');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question A', 2, '2017-06-27', '2017-06-27');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question B', 1, '2017-06-11', '2017-06-12');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question B', 2, '2017-06-13', '2017-06-13');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question B', 1, '2017-06-13', '2017-06-13');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question C', 1, '2017-06-20', '2017-06-20');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question C', 1, '2017-06-23', '2017-06-23');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question D', 2, '2017-06-01', '2017-06-01');

INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question E', 1, '2017-10-11', '2017-10-11');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question E', 1, '2017-10-15', '2017-10-15');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question F', 1, '2017-10-20', '2017-10-20');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question F', 2, '2017-10-20', '2017-10-20');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question F', 2, '2017-10-20', '2017-10-20');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question G', 1, '2017-10-26', '2017-10-26');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question H', 1, '2017-10-26', '2017-10-26');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question H', 2, '2017-10-26', '2017-10-26');
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES ('Question I', 1, '2017-10-26', '2017-10-26');
```

Here the outcome of your Query:

```
Question A  2   0   3   66,6667
Question B  2   0   3   66,6667
Question C  2   0   2   100
Question D  0   0   1   0
Question E  2   0   2   100
Question F  1   0   3   33,3333
Question G  1   0   1   100
Question H  1   0   2   50
Question I  1   0   1   100
```

I could simplify your SQL and have removed some code duplicates, maybe that was your intended question.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2017-06-01';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2017-06-30';
DECLARE @StartDate2 DATE = '2017-10-01';
DECLARE @EndDate2 DATE = '2017-10-30';

WITH 
periods AS (
SELECT @StartDate as startdate,
       @EndDate   as enddate       
UNION 
SELECT @StartDate2 as startdate,
       @EndDate2   as enddate
)
SELECT t.Question, t.Met, t.NA, t.MetNotMet,
       CASE WHEN (t.Met) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ROUND(((CONVERT(FLOAT,(t.Met))/(t.MetNotMet))* 100),4) END as CompRate
  FROM (SELECT question, 
               SUM((CASE WHEN AnswerValue = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) Met,
               SUM((CASE WHEN AnswerValue = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) NA,
               SUM((CASE WHEN (ISNULL(AnswerValue,3) <> 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) MetNotMet       
          FROM tableA AS a
          JOIN ( SELECT p.startdate,
                        p.enddate,
                        DATENAME(DAY, p.startdate) + ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, p.startdate) + ' ' + 
                          DATENAME(YEAR, p.startdate) + ' To ' + DATENAME(DAY, p.enddate) + ' ' +
                          DATENAME(MONTH, p.enddate) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, p.enddate) AS RepMonthAndYear
                   FROM periods p ) AS p ON a.startdate >= p.startdate AND a.endate <= p.enddate
         GROUP BY a.Question, p.RepMonthAndYear) AS t
```